# Downloaded NuGet package is not seen in local cache

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a .NET VS 2019 project that I am trying to build with the VS 2019 build tools (not the full installation of Visual Studio).  This project references a package found on our local NuGet server.

When I run `dotnet restore --source [nuget_server_url]`, it downloads it and puts it in `c:\users\[username\.nuget\[package_name]\`.

When I run `dotnet build`, I get the following error:

```
[project_file_path] : error NU1101: Unable to find package [package_name]. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

How do I get it to look in the local cache for that package?

Comment: is there a reason you're passing the source as a CLI parameter, and don't have a nuget.config that specifies the source to be used by default?

Comment: Would the existence/lack of a nuget.config file affect `dot build` not finding the package in the local cache?

Comment: the error messge you posted shows nuget looked for the package only on nuget.org. i don't know why your custom source isn't listed. therefore, having the source in nuget.config would allow nuget to use your custom source, and as long as your package in on that source, restore would succeed, and therefore build can work.